# jQuery: show/hide element based on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento

I want to show element with `id=attach` when the option with `value='Attached File'` is selected.  Please help me to understand why my code does not work.

My code:

```
<ul class="form-list">
  <li id="excellence-form">
    <fieldset>
      <ul>
        <li class="wide">
          <label for="excellence:like" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Initial Data') ?></label>
          <div class="input-box">
            <select class="required-entry" name="excellence[like]" id="excellence:like">
              <option value='0'><?php echo $this->__('Please Choose..');?></option>
              <option value='Not Attached' <?php if($this->getQuote()->getExcellenceLike() == 1){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $this->__('Do Not Attach File');?></option>
              <option value='Attached File' <?php if($this->getQuote()->getExcellenceLike() == 2){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $this->__('Attach File');?></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="attach" style="display:none;" >
          <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Please Attach :') ?><span id='file_upload_text'></span></label>
          <div class="input-box">
            <input id="file_upload" type="file" name="file_upload" />
          </div>
          <input id="file_upload_path" type="hidden" name="file_upload_path" class='required-entry' />
          <input type="hidden" value='Attached File' name="file_upload_type" class='required-entry' />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#excellence:like').change(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == "Attached File") {
        document.getElementById("attach").style.display="block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("attach").style.display="none";
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `#excellence:like` jQuery probably won't like this id, as both CSS and jQuery use `:` for pseudo classes and the like. try something like `#excellence-like`

Comment: why are you not using $('#attach') for document.getElementById and not .show() or .hide()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `:` in your ID (or select with `select[id='excellence:like']`):

```
$('#excellence\\:like').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "Attached File") {
        document.getElementById("attach").style.display="block";
        //jQuery alternative
        //$("#attach").show();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("attach").style.display="none";
        //jQuery alternative
        //$("#attach").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using ":" since it is a part of css selectors

try this...

```
$(function() {      
    $('.required-entry').change(function(){    // use class or use $('select')
        if ($(this).val() == "Attached File") {
            $("#attach").show();
        } else {
             $("#attach").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$(function() {
    $('#excellence\\:like').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "Attached File") {
            $("#attach").show();
        } else {
             $("#attach").hide();
        }
    });
});
```